# Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shellcheck

I need some help figuring out where my code is hitching up. The code is below:

```
servers=( Sanger )   
races=( American African Asian)
jobbs=( NCBI )      
ranges=( 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 )

for server in "${servers[@])"
do

for job in "${jobbs[@]}"
do


for race in "${races[@]}"
do

for range in "${ranges[@]}"
do

cd ${RESULTS}
cd "$server"
cd "$job"
cd "$race"
cd "$range"

for CHR in {1..22}
do

mv -v "$CHR".vcf.gz chr"$CHR".dose.vcf.gz
mv -v "$CHR".vcf.gz.csi chr"$CHR".dose.vcf.gz.csi

done   # chromo

done   # range

done   # race

done   # job

done   # server
```

My Bash terminal returns the errors:

```
./rename.sh: line 41: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./rename.sh: line 52: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

ShellCheck output is below:

```
Line 9:
for server in "${servers[@])"
               ^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this parameter expansion.

Line 32:
mv -v "$CHR".vcf.gz chr"$CHR".dose.vcf.gz
                            ^-- SC1078: Did you forget to close this double quoted string?

Line 33:
mv -v "$CHR".vcf.gz.csi chr"$CHR".dose.vcf.gz.csi
      ^-- SC1079: This is actually an end quote, but due to next char it looks suspect.
                                ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this double quoted string. Fix to allow more checks.

Line 43:
done   # server
               ^-- SC1072: Expected end of double quoted string. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Could any please help and check if I've missed something? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line 9 (according to the ShellCheck error):

```
for server in "${servers[@])"
```

You have a closing parenthesis rather than a closing brace; it should be

```
for server in "${servers[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Quarantine doing my head in.

Comment: @Jared Also indent your code properly.